# Javascript global variable doesn't work while local does

Tags: javascript, variables, audio, scope

I'm trying to make a sound when a button is pressed so the following code is inside `onclick="cNote()"`. Now, when I declare the variable locally it's working:

```
function cNote() {
var cNote = new Audio("cNote.wav");
cNote.play();
```

But when I'm declaring it as a global variable it doesn't work:

```
var cNote = new Audio("cNote.wav");

function cNote() {
cNote,play();
}
```

Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: Is the comma (cNote,play())just a typo?

Comment: When asking a question, it is generally very helpful to explain what the problem is in more detail than that something just "doesn't work."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've given the variable and the function the same name. There can only be one symbol with a given name in any scope.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, didn't notice it :P

Comment: Another question, when the variables are global there's a delay between two same audios, for example, if I trigger an audio and the triggers another, it's flowless. But when I'm triggering a note and trigger it again, there's like a small "respawn" for that audio though the input is recieved.

When the variables are local, I can play notes as fast as I want to.

is there any work around for it not to happen?

Comment: The variables being local or global really should not make any appreciable difference. If you post the code in a new question there may be something that somebody can explain.